# Ошибка обобщения

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Есть много сущностей, которые наследуются от класса `BaseEntity<TKey>`. Операции, которые необходимо проводить над сущностями, абсолютно одинаковые, по этому был создан класс `DataService<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity: BaseEntity<TKey>`. В методах класса возникает ошибка при использовании ключа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это один и тот же тип, но компилятор этого признавать не хочет. Как это исправить?

Пример кода, приводящего к ошибке:

```
public Task<BaseEntity<TKey>> Get(TKey id)
{
    return DataService.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
}
```

Ограничения `where TKey : IComparable, IEquatable<TKey>` ошибку не исправляют

Comment: Во-первых, используйте `IComparable<TKey>`, а не `IComparable`. Во-вторых, это не исправит ошибку. Вам нужно дергать метод `CompareTo` вместо `<`, `>` или `==`.

Comment: Т.е. ваш код превратится в `...FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.CompareTo(id) == 0)`. Или в `u => u.Id.CompareTo(id) < 0)` если нужно выбрать все элементы с идентификаторами, которые меньше, чем id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор признает, что это один и тот же тип. Он говорит, что у этого типа может не быть оператора `==`.

Ты можешь использовать вместо него метод `Equals`, который должен быть переопределён у всех типов, у которых есть переопределение оператора `==`.

Если речь о ссылочных типах, и необходимо сравнение по ссылке `ReferenceEquals`. Так же вы можете добавить ограничение для TKey - `IComparable` или `IEquatable` и использовать методы этих интерфейсов для сравнения.

Comment: DataService является IQueryable. Мне нужно чтобы можно было использовать все операторы вроде >,<, != и так далее. IComparabl не помог.

Comment: При сравнении из вне ограничения не помогают, ни IComparable, ни IEquatable

Comment: @mirypoko: А вы всё ещё сравниваете через ==, или через Equals?

Comment: @VladD через Equals работает, но мне еще нужно различные  >,<, которые не работают

Comment: @mirypoko в тот момент, когда тип будет известен, компилятор разрешит вам подобное сравнение. До тех пор, у вас есть только один выход - использование `dynamic`. Он позволяет вызывать неизвестные члены, в том числе операторы. Но мне не кажется это хорошей идеей. Возможно, просто не стоит строить запросы на неизвестных типах или отказаться от `TKey` в пользу, скажем, `Guid`?

Comment: @mirypoko: А через `IComparable<T>`/`CompareTo` работает? (Вам это же пишет другой Vlad в комментарии сверху)